# Does it make sense to limit Sympy's infinity?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a problem with inequality math with the following problem. with x [image: variable] on

[image: the picture]

The result I want is like this this [image]

my code

```
from sympy import *
x  = symbols('x', real=True)
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
ekpr = Rational(1, 2)*x + 3 <= Rational(1, 5)*x
Hp = solve(ekpr, x)
sol = (Hp).as_set() & Range(-oo,oo) 
sol
```

the output is like this [image: picture]

And I'm struggling to get the result I want, to be able to add -15, -14 to infinity sympy. until this is the last code of my struggle, but it still fails too.

```
Interval(x = -15, x = -14).as_relational(sol)
```

So that the results are as I want like this [image: picture].

Thank you, any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hp` is your solution which extends from -10 to negative infinity. You wish to constrain this to the integers in `[-15, 0]`. You have nearly done this in what you have shown:

```py
>>> Hp.as_set() & Range(-15,1)  # [-15, 1) = [-15, 0]
{-15, -14, ..., -10}
```

Alternatively, you could give the range as the domain for `solveset`:

```py
>>> solveset(ekpr, x, Range(-15,1))
{-15, -14, ..., -10}
```